# Reading from a file in assembly line by line

Tags: assembly, file-io, x86, dos

How can I read line by line in 8086 ?
I want to read names with marks as:

```
Saleem Atia 79
Fadi Jameel 50
Hamad Mohsen 90
Maen Mohamamd 97
Yezan Safi 87
Sufyan Naim 88
Mohammad Mosa 32
Amera Skafe 65
Mohammad Akr 90
```

How can I do this?
I use this code, but it doesn't work:

```
.model small
.stack 100
.data 

    fname1 db "Gr_Sec1.txt",0
    fname2 db "Gr_Sec2.txt",0
    fname3 db "Gr_Sec3.txt",0
    text db 100
         db 0
             db 100 dup(0)
    fhand dw ?

.code
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax

    mov ah,3dh
    mov al,0
    lea dx,fname1
    int 21h
    mov fhand,ax
    mov si,0
L:

    mov ah,3fh
    mov bx,fhand
    mov cx,1
    lea dx,text+si
    int 21h
    cmp ax,0
    JE EXIT
    INC SI
    JMP L

EXIT:

    MOV BYTE PTR text+si,"$"
    MOV AH,3EH
    INT 21H

    mov ah,9
    lea dx,text
    int 21h

    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h
end
```

Comment: How does it not work? Have you debugged the program? Comment your code if you want other people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I do not find an error in the code, but maybe the file to load can not be found in the same directory. This can be checked with the carry flag after the OPEN interrupt call. CF clear if successful, else there is an error. And the executable need the real mode, or the v86 mode for to execute. For 64 bit windows it need an emulator like DOSBOX.

What does the console screen show after running the program, nothing?